# Getting data from API in C#

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to get data from a open API using C#.

In my code below, I manage to create a `HttpClient` object, but I can't get a http response. I have some `Console.Writeline()` to help me locate the error, and the last thing I print is

> Created HTTP Client

So I don't seem to get a response. Can any one tell me what is wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace CodeTesting
{
    public class Parser
    {
        public Parser()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Created parser");
            GetQuestion();
        }

        public static async void GetQuestion()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INSIDE GETQUESTION");
            string baseUrl = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=15&difficulty=easy";

            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Created HTTPClient");

                    using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("GOT HTTP RESPONSE");

                        using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("RETRIEVING CONTENT");
                            var data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            if (data != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("data------------{0}", data);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("NO Data----------");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Hit------------");
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: Are you getting an error or does it simply not continue to the `Console.WriteLine(("GOT HTTP RESPONSE");)` step? Your program might be just waiting for a response. Have you tried setting a breakpoint at the `await client.GetAsync(baseurl)` line?

Comment: Your code never awaits for `GetQuestion()` to complete. Most likely, it terminates before a response is received. *Don't* call asynchronous methods in the constructor

Comment: `async void` is only meant for event handlers and can't be awaited. Use `async Task` for asynchronous methods that return no data.

Comment: Try removing the "await".  The await will block until the connection is closed, not when you get the end of the response.  The server is not closing the connection so you are blocked.

Comment: You can use RestSharp, it wlll help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the await from HttpResponseMessage and add ".Result" at the end of GetAsync() function, below code is working.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace CodeTesting
{
    public class Parser
    {
        public Parser()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Created parser");
            GetQuestion();
        }
        public static async void GetQuestion()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INSIDE GETQUESTION");
            string baseUrl = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=15&difficulty=easy";

            try
            {

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Created HTTPClient");

                    using (HttpResponseMessage res = client.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("GOT HTTP RESPONSE");

                        using (HttpContent content = res.Content)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("RETRIEVING CONTENT");

                            var data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            if (data != null)
                            { Console.WriteLine("data------------{0}", data);}
                            else
                            { Console.WriteLine("NO Data----------"); }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Hit------------");
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for the http client to fetch the values.
So your parser would be something like this,

```
public Parser()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Created parser");
            GetQuestion();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Note : This is not the solution but to unblock you, try this so that you can view the output.

Output:

> Created parser
>   INSIDE GETQUESTION
>   Created HTTPClient
>   GOT HTTP RESPONSE
>   RETRIEVING CONTENT
>   data------------{"response_code":0,"results":[{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"What was the name of the cancelled sequel of Team Fortress?","correct_answer":"Team Fortress 2: Brotherhood of Arms","incorrect_answers":["Team Fortress 2: Desert Mercenaries","Team Fortress 2: Operation Gear Grinder","Team Fortress 2: Return to Classic"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"boolean","difficulty":"easy","question":"In "Super Mario 64", collecting 100 coins on a level will give you a 1-UP.","correct_answer":"False","incorrect_answers":["True"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"boolean","difficulty":"easy","question":"Niko Bellic is the protagonist of Grand Theft Auto IV.","correct_answer":"True","incorrect_answers":["False"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"What year did the game "Overwatch" enter closed beta?","correct_answer":"2015","incorrect_answers":["2013","2011","2016"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"How many differently shaped Tetris pieces are there?","correct_answer":"7","incorrect_answers":["5","6","8"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"What video game sparked controversy because of its hidden "Hot Coffee" minigame?","correct_answer":"Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas","incorrect_answers":["Grand Theft Auto: Vice City","Hitman: Blood Money","Cooking Mama"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"The name of the Metroid series comes from what?","correct_answer":"An enemy in the game","incorrect_answers":["The final boss's name","The main character's name","A spaceship's name"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"Which of the following was NOT a playable character in the game Kingdom Hearts: Birth by Sleep?","correct_answer":"Ignis","incorrect_answers":["Ventus","Terra","Aqua"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"Who turns out to be the true victor in the Battle of Armageddon in Mortal Kombat?","correct_answer":"Shao Kahn","incorrect_answers":["Liu Kang","Shang Tsung","Raiden"]},{"category":"Entertainment: Video Games","type":"multiple","difficulty":"easy","question":"In "Mario & Sonic at the Olympic Games", characters are split into how many types?","correct_answer":"4","incorrect_answers":["6","5","3"]}]}